# What Express.js template uses HTML as is?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, pug

I am looking for a template that uses HTML as is , it should be somthing like Jade but without modifying HTML language .

**The purpose of this question is that**:

1. I find HTML clear and easy enough
2. I want to view my pages "or part of it" in MS-Expression or other
   simple web design softwares

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handlebars could be what you're looking for.
The templating engine: http://handlebarsjs.com/
Implementation for express.js: https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars

Answer (score 2):

You could try `EJS`  template engine instead.

http://www.embeddedjs.com/

To enable this in express, run this command in the root of your project to install `EJS`.

`npm install ejs --save`

Then open your `app.js` file and change the line.

`app.set('view engine', 'jade');`

to

`app.set('view engine', 'ejs');`

This should allow you to use `EJS` instead of `Jade` in your templates, saving the files as `example.ejs`.

Comment: Can I use this with node.js and express.js ?

Comment: Sure you can! See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply send static file with express:

```
express.static()
```

You can't inject data into template if you use that.
You better use template engines.

You can easily built your own.
[Developing template engines for Express](http://expressjs.com/advanced/developing-template-engines.html)

Comment: I dont want just to pass files as they are, there will be variables to replace and more. as the question said it should be something like jade with HTML unchanged.

Comment: just updated. you can create custom templating engine

Comment: That looks interesting , I am checking it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use .html document with ejs render:

```
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```